# Call function of StatefulWidget from StatelessWidget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, stateless, stateful

I want to call a function from my StatefulWidget when a button in my StatelessWidget is pressed. In the following code you can see what I'm trying to do. I'm not really sure how it works, so maybe you can help me.

StatelessWidget - Button should call function from StatefulWidget

```
class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SafeArea(child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: ProgressButton.icon(iconedButtons: {not needed}
                    onPressed: addUser,
                    state: ButtonState.idle),
              ),
            ],
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Statefulwidget - addUser() should be called by StatelessWidget

```
class HomeStateful extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeStatefulState createState() => _HomeStatefulState();
}

class _HomeStatefulState extends State<HomeStateful> {
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    HomeWidget(),
    MessageWidget(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: onTabTapped,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text("Home"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
              title: Text("Nachrichten"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void addUser() {
    firestoreInstance.collection("users").add({
      "vorname": prenameController,
      "nachname": nameController,
      "geburtstag": birthdayController,
      "adresse": adressController,
      "telefon": numberController,
      "id": 0
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callback function in Stateless widget, Like this

```
class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeWidget({Key key, @required this.addUser}) : super(key: key);

  /// If you want to pass any value back, then you can use something
  /// like this
  /// final Function(User user) addUser;

  /// VoidCallback as name speaks its a empty fn.
  final VoidCallback addUser; // ==> Here is the answer.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: addUser, // Add User fun here
                  )),
            ],
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And in stateful/parent widget.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 
  final _list = <Widget>[
    HomeWidget(addUser: addUser) // Wrong, You cannot access the addUser here.
  ];

   final _childList = <Widget>[];// But you can initialize here and add the HomeWidget in initState.
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _childList.addAll([
      HomeWidget(addUser: addUser),
      HomeWidget(addUser: addUser),

      ///... Other children
    ]);
  }

  void addUser() {
    // Do Somethign
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        HomeWidget(addUser: addUser),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement it into my project right now. Seems to work but there is one error: `final List<Widget> _children = [
    HomeWidget(addUser: addUser),
    MessageWidget(),
  ];` - So I tried to use the function in my StatefulWidget as described. Error: The instance member 'addUser' can't be accessed in an initializer. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This issues mainly occur due to constructor which is not pass but you don't want to pass constructor so you can use single key constructor that will help in calling.
Example

```
class ExampleTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleTwo({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _ExampleTwoState createState() => _ExampleTwoState();
}

class _ExampleTwoState extends State<ExampleTwo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Lesson 1 Example 1'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      body: const Center(
          child: Text(
        'State Ful widget ',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24),
      )),
    );
  }
}
//State Less widget 

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: ExampleTwo(),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this will give you an idea if not ping.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ok i will check in the help center. – 
Community Bot